# Biggest volume parallelotope inside the union of two parallelotopes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Given a parallelotope $P$ symmetric around the origin, and a vector $v$, such that $(P+v)∩(P−v)$ is not empty, is there a simple way to obtain a parallelotope $Q⊂(P+v)∪(P−v)$, symmetric around the origin, with the largest volume?

The dimension 2 case was answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/203239/39359, where Pietro argued that it is enough to look at the case where $P$ is a unit cube. It turns out that the best parallelograms will have an edge parallel to the original square. Is there a generalization of this result in more dimensions?

Thanks!